# Can not mount my USB disk-- Ubuntu nor windows[dmesg including]

Tags: windows, ubuntu, usb, mount, usb-flash-drive

First, here is my `dmesg | tail` result right after I plugged the disk in:

```
 $ dmesg | tail
[ 2578.697224] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access HP v100w PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 2578.698322] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 2578.916464] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 3921920 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 GB/1.87 GiB)
[ 2578.916950] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 2578.916956] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 2578.916961] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2578.922460] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2578.922470] sdb:
[ 2578.969570] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2578.969578] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

There is nothing after "sdb"...

In the meantime, `lsusb` shows:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 03f0:3207 Hewlett-Packard
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 045e:0737 Microsoft Corp.
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Can anyone help me?  What's wrong with my USB disk?

Answer (score 2):

Some USB devices need to be mounted directly, as in

`mount /dev/sdb /mnt`

(no partition number given). Try it and see what happens.

Comment: My drive is /dev/sdd but that command gives `mount: no medium found on /dev/sdd`.

Answer (score 2):

maybe it is a problem with the udev rules?

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 03f0:3207 Hewlett-Packard
```

Then use that "Bus 002 Device 004" and check what

```
udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/bus/usb/002/004)
```

And then you find something like this at the top

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-4':
```

And that you can put into udevadm to test what happens with the udev rules.

```
sudo udevadm test /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-4
```

And look for stuff like

```
udev_rules_apply_to_event:
```

And if you need to change them this page is a good start.

- http://raftaman.net/?p=343
- http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your drive, at least I can't see anything unusual. The only strange thing, there is no "sdb1" despite the fact that its a pendrive. Try creating a partition with gparted (sudo apt-get install gparted && sudo gparted). .. Last time I ended up spending quite a time with messing my pendrive.

Comment: DO NOT create a partition table unless you're CERTAIN there's no filesystem present.  **it will blow away any existing filesystem and data.**

Comment: Of course it'll, thats common sense.

Comment: it's common sense if you know it already.  please, give explict warnings when you advise dangerous operations -- readers of this site are potentially unsophisticated users and may not understand all the ramifications of following your advice.  thanks!

Comment: nope.. at first, this way does not work.... there is no device in gparted

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
```

Are there any partitions on the disk?  Then try mounting a likely one manually.  If you don't understand the result, add it to your question above.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be your USB device, but your USB port may not be able to provide sufficient power for the device.

On my machine, most devices work fine, but I have one USB drive that only works when plugged into one of the rear ports, which are directly on the MB.  Symptioms in this case are very similar to your results.

Options are to try a different port, or to get a powered USB hub.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it didn't work in any USB port. 
But while reading the last answer I remembered that my HD adapter came with a double usb cable  and everything worked pretty well when I used it.